# Plantilla no válida en los inputs de una GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

Tengo una acción de GitHub que disparo manualmente y recibe en sus imputs algunos Numbers pero al intentar pasarlos a un job me está dando el error:

> The template is not valid.
> Unexpected type of value '1.0', expected type: Number.

Estoy pasando mis inputs con la expresión `${{ inputs.myNumberInput }}`, en concreto mi YAML es:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myNumberInput:
        description: My number
        type: choice
        options:
          - 0
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
          - 4
          - 5

jobs:
  checkout_repository:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
  deploy:
    needs: checkout_repository
    uses: ./.github/workflows/my-workflow.yaml
    with:
      myNumber: ${{ inputs.myNumberInput }}
```

Ya estuve investigando en la documentación de GitHub pero no encuentro nada, tengo que hacer algún casteo especial o algo para que el valor del input pase bien?

Comment: [Revisa bien](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs). Los inputs del `workflow_dispatch` tienen tipos string, choice, boolean y environment. No se ve number por ahí...

Comment: @Alfabravo encontré la documentación que mencionas muchas gracias, sin embargo sigue pasando lo mismo, actualicé mi pregunta con los últimos cambios usando choice